# URL rewrite to remove index.php and sub folder not working?

Tags: codeigniter, url-rewriting, dreamhost

So I've gone through dozens of forum posts and websites between dreamhost, codeingiter etc.

I have a file directory set up in codeigniter hosted on dreamhost as follows:

```
mysite.com
 - application
 - system
 - user_guide
 - .htaccess
```

The live site I can access is:

```
mysite.com/index.php/site/WhatIwantToKeep
```

My `.htaccess` file reads:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Currently if I go to `mysite.com/site/WhatIwantToKeep` it can't find it.

If I place any `IfModule` tags or options lines, it gives a server 500 error.

Ideally this code would rewrite it so that my URLs would be reading:

```
mysite.com/WhatIwantToKeep
```

Comment: How is your routers, default controller settings on the codeigniter config?

Comment: Yeah, show us your routes.php file.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following in my `.htaccess` file. Give it a shot:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^([a-zA-z0-9/])
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index.php|images|robots.txt|system|assets|files)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1 [QSA,L]
```